# Extract fullpath with matching filename

Tags: bash, text-processing, macos

I have text file that contain list of fullpath of files from a harddrive. This can be thousand lines, but here a sample of my `volume_content.txt` file:

```
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_A/VID_A002C001.mov
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_A/VID_A002C003.mov
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_A/VID_A003C003.mov
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_B/CARD01/20200905/TVC.mov
```

Let say I have search keywords inside `footages.txt`, but these keywords should be refer to the filename only:

```
A002
TVC
```

If I use

```
footage=$(cat footages.txt)
cat volume_content.txt | grep "${footage}"
```

it will end up collecting whole content of my `volume_content.txt`, since each line had pattern `TVC` on it.

I have manage to extract the correct lines, by sort it using `grep` twice, by using :

```
footage=$(cat footages.txt)
cat volume_content.txt | sed 's!.*/!!' | grep "${footage}" > footage_filename.txt
footage_filename=$(cat footage_filename.txt)
cat volume_content.txt | grep "${footage_filename}" > all_footages.txt
```

And this is the result, which is this is what I want :

```
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_A/VID_A002C001.mov
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_A/VID_A002C003.mov
/Volumes/NEW TVC/20200901/CAM_B/CARD01/20200905/TVC.mov
```

Is there simple way (probably one liner) to achieve this?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to cat a file of patterns into a variable to pass as an argument to grep; just use `grep -f footages.txt` instead.  You also don't need to cat a file into a pipe to grep, as grep can read from files specified on the command line.  Your first code snippet can thus be simplified to `grep -f footages.txt volume_content.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following one-liner should work:

```
awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR {pat=pat ? pat "|" $0 : $0; next} $NF ~ pat' footages.txt volume_content.txt
```

This processes first `footages.txt` and generates a regular expression consisting of the ORed individual patterns read from each line. This regular expression is stored in an internal variable `pat` and would look like `A002|TVC` in your example case. The somewhat cryptic `pat=pat ? pat "|" $0 : $0` means "if `pat` is already used, set `pat=pat "|" $0`, else set `pat=$0`". **Note** that some more effort would be needed if the patterns in `footages.txt` were themselves actual regular expressions!

When processing `volume_content.txt`, it splits every line at the `/` and checks if the last path component matches the previously assembled regular expression `pat`. If so, the line is printed (because the condition `$NF ~ pat`, which is placed *outside* any rule block, evaluates to "true").

Setting `/` as field separator doesn't interfere with parsing `footages.txt` because we only consider entire lines there anyway.

The distinction between whether we are processing the first file or any later files is via the condition `NR==FNR`, which compares the global line counter `NR` with the per-file line-counter `FNR`. If they are equal, it is the first file.